# How to get Comma separated Values IN SQL from 2 different tables using isnull stuff

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi i have 2 different table "Users" and "UsersReportsTo" 
there are two column as foreign key in UsersReportsTo Table column1 = Userid and column2 = ReportsTo, both contains userids

The result i want is comma separated email id of reportsto

please see the image

[image]

one user can report to multiple users like one teamleader to multiple assistance

i have tried below query but i am not getting proper result

```
select isnull(STUFF((SELECT ',' + Email 
                     from UsersReportsTo urt 
                     Left join Users rpt WITH (NOLOCK) on rpt.UserID=urt.UserID 
                     WHERE active=1  and urt.UserID = 425 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''),'') as rept 
from UsersReportsTo
```

if i want Reportsto for UserId =3

Expected Result :-

```
qrst@g.com,abc@g.com,efg@g.com
```

Comment: What technology are you using?  SQL-Server, MYSQL, Oracle, other?  You said you are not getting proper results, what are you getting?

Comment: Checkout the function COALESCE (if supported by your DBMS).

Comment: @ Brad ,technology  - SQL-Server 2012 ,  I am getting empty rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou for all your help.
I figured it out , selection of email id would be from users table my query was wrong now i found it, below is what i did.

select isnull(stuff((select',' + Email 
                    from Users
                     left join UsersReportsTo  WITH (NOLOCK) on UsersReportsTo.ReportsTo = Users.UserID
                     where  Users.active = 1 and UsersReportsTo.userID = 425
                     for xml path('')), 1, 1, ''),'') as reptoemail

Answer (score 0):

You just need correct your where clause inside `stuff()` function:

```
select isnull(stuff((select',' + Email 
                     from UsersReportsTo urt 
                     left join Users rpt WITH (NOLOCK) on rpt.UserID = urt.ReportsTo
                     where u.userid = rpt.UserID and active = 1
                     for xml path('')), 1, 1, ''),'') as rept 
from UsersReportsTo u
where UserId = 3
group by u.UserId;
```

Also read [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

If, you have latest version of SQL Server (2017), then you can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function

Answer (score 0):

try this in a query window and run it

```
WITH Email as       (
                                SELECT          rpt.Email as emailaddress
                                FROM                Users rpt
                                WHERE           active=1  
                                AND                 urt.UserID = 3
                                UNION ALL 
                                SELECT          rpt2.Email as emailaddress
                                FROM                UsersReportsTo urt --Teams
                                LEFT JOIN       Users rpt WITH (NOLOCK) on urt.UserID = rpt.UserID 
                                LEFT JOIN       Users rpt2 WITH (NOLOCK) on rpt2.UserID=urt.ReportsTo 
                                WHERE           active=1  
                                AND                 urt.UserID = 3
                                )

select isnull(STUFF((SELECT  ',' + emailaddress from Email
                                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''),'') as rept
```

You are seleting the user, then unioning the team leaders. From this cte you can delimit the list